# Ajax responseText parsing to undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to read a return body of a POST ajax call. It's returning an object "message" with a pair value regarding its price.

For some reason when I try to retrieve the "message"'s value I get undefined. I have tried a few methods including JSON.parse.

**I don't want** to simply string.replace out the content from the raw string as that would be a messy and ineffective solution.

In this specific example I am trying to retrieve *"Please deposit: 1.50"*

My function:

```
.always(function(returnBody){
console.log("raw: " + returnBody.responseText);

var parsed = JSON.parse(returnBody.responseText);
var item = parsed[0];

console.log("stringified: " + JSON.stringify(item));
```

My log content:

```
raw: {"message":"Please deposit: 1.50"}
stringified: undefined
```

Comment: what does `console.log(parsed)` or `console.log(parsed.message)` look like?

Comment: {message: 'Please deposit: 1.50'}
Please deposit: 1.50


2nd one works, thank you!!

Comment: Ok, solved - voting to close as a typo